# Reformat XML data from junk tags using Python

Tags: python, xml, splunk

I am new to Splunk tool, trying to write a code that having a XML data output which is coming from splunk, the output is having junk tags in between and format is also not in order.Is there any way to reformat the XML data using Modular Input splunk in python.

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your code, some input and some output so we can try to help

Comment: I have a data as string in text file(Input file) shown below. I need to remove junk data and if there is any xml tags in a given string, need to collect xml data and save it in another folder

Input :

<Hello> <Message><stdout>"weblogic.servelt.Default(self-tuning)"] <12-18-2020> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><breakfast_menu><food><name>Belgian Waffles</name><price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description><calories>650</calories></food><food><name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>

Comment: Output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>
Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>
Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

Comment: This elaborate data belongs in the question itself. Please add it there.